# Disable httpclient wire content log using GWT debug mode and logback

Tags: gwt, httpclient, logback

When using GWT on debug mode, I'm getting lots of logs from the httpclient wire.
I'm using logback.

I followed several conversations here how to disable this logging by setting the apache httpclient wire logger level to WARN, but it doesn't work for me.
I also tried to set up the logback root level to INFO - but I'm still getting DEBUG levels from the httpclient.

Anyone managed to disable the httpclient wire logger on GWT using logback?

This what I've tried:

```
<logger name="org.apache" level="WARN" />
<logger name="org.apache.axis2" level="WARN" />
<logger name="org.apache.axiom" level="WARN" />
<logger name="httpclient.wire" level="WARN" />
<logger name="org.springframework" level="warn" />

<root level="INFO">
<appender-ref ref="${logback.appender}" />
</root>
```

Thanks,
Ben

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I found out, you need to add the logback.xml to the GWT run configuration classpath...