# GWT and Maven 3- Disable / change debug level from Eclipse console

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, gwt, errai

How to exclude the follwing Info mentioned in image from eclipse console while running a gwt project in development mode. ?
I m using Eclipse Juno and Maven 3. 
[image]

Comment: see this
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10160640/disable-httpclient-wire-content-log-using-gwt-debug-mode-and-logback

Comment: Thanks for the response !! Helpful....